# Updating dataset/datatable with various UPDATE queries

Tags: vb.net, delegates

I have a vb.net project where I have data loaded into a data table in a dataset and have to do approximately 20 updates that are SQL like.  On this project, I don't have access to SQL nor does the end user want to use any type of SQL, SQL express etc.

My question is,  is there a generic way of doing this so I can reuse it.  Was wondering if a dataview could be analogous to the `WHERE CLAUSE` and some type of delegate function could be the update function.

For example,  let's say I need to update the rows where the customer city is Berlin,  the logic would look like

```
dim view as new dataview
view.Table = ds.tables("CustomerData")
view.RowFilter = "City = 'Berlin'"

for each row in view
    SOMEHOW INSERT DELEGATE HERE
next
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function and pass in a datatable and filter name. Return a dataview with the desired filter. This can then be saved in another dataview variable.

Same way, create a function for update or insert, pass in the datatable reference and a list of parameters for all the columns and a value to determine whether to insert or update (Like Primary Key). Return updated datatable which you will replace in existing variable.